# To what extent did the "Arab Spring" protesters meet their goals?

Tags: revolution, africa, egypt, arabia, arab-spring

Too what extent did the protesters throughout the Arab spring in Tunisia, Libya and Egypt achieve their aims?

What happened after the various regimes resigned, what has changed and what would the protesters still like to see happen in their country.

Comment: Is this really history yet?  It's rather on going.  The outcomes in many of these events haven't really come to completion.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment and @DVK response here (noting the multiple actors amongst the protesters), there is also the issue of economic, cultural, and institutional differences between the three nations.  It is too early to tell for instance in Egypt if the military will relinquish control as promised in July or if the left and liberal minority will succeed in the goals outlined in their alternate constitution, which isn't drafted yet.  And that's just Egypt.

Comment: A narrower question would be stronger.

Answer (score 5):

**Libya:**

Gaddafi was ousted from power and killed. Most of his sons (heirs) are in captivity or dead. Right now, the interim government is still trying to find its place. There are still conflicts going on. Libya is a tribal country, and there are reports of cells of Gaddafi loyalists still fighting on. The situation there is still very fragile and hard to predict. The National Transition Council is still in the process of drafting election laws.

**Tunisia:**

Former President *Ben Ali* was deposed and remains in self imposed exile. The Tunisians have just had their first elections, and have elected their first post revolution president (former dissident and centrist secularist *Marzouki*) and a constituent assembly where the majority of the seats went to the Islamist party *Nahda*. They are in the process of reforming the Tunisian constitution.

**Egypt:**

Even though president Mubrarak has stepped down and is undergoing corruption trials (along with several of members of his cabinet), the interim military government has yet to relinquish control, although they have relaxed the emergency laws that have been in place since 1958, though not fully lifted them. 
The Egyptian people have just recently finished electing a new parliament, where again formerly banned Islamists have won the majority of the seats. There have been mixed results from them. On one hand, the new government has declared that it would not break the peace with Israel. On the other hand, there has been more and more cases of legal prosecution against anti-Islamic free speech. Egypt's situation remains very volatile.

**Syria:**

The country seems to sinking deeper and deeper into a state of civil war. Although the Syrian regime has been ostracized by the international community and its fellow Arab nations, it still has an ally in Iran. Russia and China as well seem to be determined to veto any UN sanctioned actions against Assad's government.

Comment: While this is a good summary of the state of affairs, it doesn't answer "meet their goals" - in large part, because the question didn't bother narrowing down what the goals are (and it's VERY hard to pin down due to multiple stakeholders)

Answer (score 2):

In **Libya** they completely ousted the regime and they are in an intermediate phase towards implementing democracy.

In **Egypt** they namely ousted the official dictator, but *de facto* nothing changed: the military are still in power and are oppressing the people much more than before. The protesters must certainly hope to somehow remove the military from power.

Comment: Any why on Earth did this post deserve a downvote?

Comment: I am unable to tag you, sorry.
I can tell you why i downvoted - Lybia isn't in an "intermediate phase towards implementing democracy". There are two independent groups that control most of the country, each for themselves. So far, peace between them has not been negotiated, even with UN help. They are no more close to democracy than... Saudi Arabia.
As for Egypt, the protests were NEVER against the army -in fact, most of the people welcomed the army intervention against the "democratically elected"[if that doesn't speak volumes,i don't know what will] representative of a former terrorist group

Answer (score 1):

I think even now about 4 or 5 years later it is too early to give a clear answer of the Question.

As for example in neither Syria, Libya, Egypt, Bahrain nor Yemen we have a really positive change of the situation.

Yes **in Egypt** the people got ride of Mubarak at first, but now even if he's no more ruling the country he was absolved from any accusation and is a free man! Nothing has changed as after the first democratic election in the country the President was imprisoned after a (more or less supported by the public masses) Military putsch and condemned to death! People are neither free nor having enough food nor any positive perspective only a stable regime due to the "Military putsch"!

**In Libya**, yes Gadahaffi and his family have no more power and most of them have been either killed, imprisoned or living in Exile in Algeria (AFAIK). But the country is a mess and a big factor of instability is the strengthened ISIL there, as we still don't even have a real administration there!

**In Bahrain** the Saudi's and their Vassals could freeze the revolt of the Shi'i majority ruled by a pro Saudi Sunni minority before it got out of control.

**In Yemen** Salah is still alive and conspiring with the Houthies to get back to power. The Land is in a civil war, Saudis and Vassals again are fighting the pro iranian/shi'i Houthies!

**In Syria** the civil war has not yet come to an end while the power of ISIL raises there and in the Iraq day by day. And now Assad's regime could be a partner in the anti-ISIL campaign. The whole country is a mess everybody is fighting each other. The protest movement for more democracy ended up in a "religious conflict" with apparently "endless dimensions".

**In Tunisia** everything seems to go a good way, but the regime isn't yet stable and still assassination attempts could create some trouble. Especially as the neighbor countries are also not really stable and could export some trouble. Libya -> ISIL, Algeria actually a conflict with the Kabyle Berbers who try to revolt against the Military regime which really rules the country instead of a marionette President [Bouteflika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdelaziz_Bouteflika) who might already be brain dead. A few days ago i just read news that the Algerian intelligence service works hand in hand with terrorists to destabilize the security of Tunisia and helped the assassins to overcome the Tunisian frontier. And we shouldn't forget that the [actual President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beji_Caid_Essebsi) is like [Sisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdel_Fattah_el-Sisi) in Egypt from the ancient Garde of the Ben Ali regime. But it's the most promising Land where the protesters might have a chance to meet their goals. As they are many steps ahead in democracy compared to other Arabic countries!

Comment: Slight note on Egypt - the "President" Morsi was protested against, and only then did the Army intervene. So, in a way, the Army was following the will of the people(and the majority of the Egyptians approved of it's actions, according to various polls). Furthermore i'd like to add that Morsi was a member of a former terrorist group legalized just before the elections. Whatever nutjob thought he has the right to run for president should be executed as well.

Comment: Well but they could have waited for the next elections to get ride of him! And even if the army did the will of the people i can't even imagine that the actual situation was the will of the people!

Comment: @AdrianTodorov Every time someone protests in the streets, someone in that groups claims to represent "the majority" of the country. Imperfect as it may be, the only actual way to measure actual intentions is through elections. The fact that elections following the coup have had 38.6% and 46% turnout (and the latter only after the military added an unscheduled additional election day) makes it very difficult to support that the military coup has the backing of the Egyptian public.