# Why did the Arab spring and Iranian Green movement failed for the most part, but the European revolution did not?

Tags: europe, middle-east, iran

Why did the Arab spring back a few years ago failed for the most part, the Iranian green movement didn't get the result it wanted, but the European revolutions (such as the French revolution, Revolutions of 1848) was able to reform a continent with conservative religion views and a set of dictatorship governments into a significantly more free and liberal region?

Comment: Exactly which "European Revolution" are you referring to in your question? I'm also not sure that the "Arab Spring" failed quite as much as you seem to believe.

Comment: @CGCampbell Revolutions between 1500 to 1900 such as the french revolution or revolutions of 1848

Comment: The Arab Spring is less than a decade old. Compared to the "European Revolutions" spanning multiple centuries, wouldn't you say that it was a smashing success? Or at least too early to tell?

Comment: I think you have things backwards.  It isn't the various European revolutions that diminished the influence of religion, but rather that those revolutions could happen (in large part) because other factors (science, mainly) had diminished the effects of religion.

Comment: Isn't it a bit too early to talk about 2011 as "history" ?! I guess it's best to answer this on Politics SE - espcially considering you asked the same question there.

Comment: This question was cross-posted by the same user on both History SE and Politics SE: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10288/why-did-arab-spring-and-iranian-green-revolution-failed-but-the-european-revolut

Comment: Sidenote: 1848/49 Hungarian revolution also failed (even if Hungary could fight out some decent position inside the empire few decades after the revolution)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs more to Politics SE than History.

Comment: Maybe relevant http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/to-what-extent-did-the-arab-spring-protesters-meet-their-goals

Answer (score 13):

There were plenty of European revolutions which led to terrible casualties and not much democracy, both before and after the French revolution.

- The [Hussite wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hussite_Wars).
- The [English revolution of 1688](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution).
- The [German revolutions of 1848/49](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_revolutions_of_1848%E2%80%9349).
- The [Paris commune of 1870](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Commune).

The revolutionaries simply tried again, or they faded away when conditions changed.

Comment: +1 - Europe switching from mostly monarchies to mostly liberal democracies was a long and exceptionally bloody process. It took the better part of 3 centuries, and is still going on at the margins. To riff on Bonhoeffer, cheap freedom is no more effective than cheap Grace.

Comment: @T.E.D. Nice summary that covers a lot of ground.